# Centering widthless elements

Tags: css

I was trying to center an element (a `div` with a `h1` in it) within a full width footer and came across some behaviour I didn't understand: Not until I added a `width` (and removed `inline-block`) to the `footer-inner` container was it centered, even when swapping out the `h1` for an `img` I get the same result, the element is hard left .

HTML

```
<div class="footer-outer">
    <div class="footer-inner">
        <h1>Foo Barson</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.footer-outer {
    width: 100%;
    border: 2px green solid;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0px;
}

.footer-inner {
    border: 2px red solid;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: inline-block;
    /* width: 144px; */
}

.footer-inner h1 {
    border: 2px black dashed;
    font-size: 130%;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LGEen/) for it.

I'd like to understand when an element is 'widthless'. If you could explain or point me to some reading that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you just add `text-align:center` to `.footer-outer`. That will center the `h1` for you

http://jsfiddle.net/feitla/LGEen/3/

Comment: Yeah, `text-align` is how I got there in the end - but mostly I'm looking for the reason why this happens.